# git remote add new-origin only effects master branch, remaining branches are not effected

Tags: git, git-push

I cloned a git repository which has 10 branches. For this repository I added

```
$git remote add new-origin url
```

when i add new-origin remote, only master branch is affected
like,

**remotes/new-origin/master**

remotes/origin/master

remotes/origin/dev1
..
..

and When I run

```
$git push new-origin --all
```

Only master branch is pushed to new repository, and remaining branches are not pushed.

**How can I push all branches to new repository without deleting the repository origin.**     (without mirroring)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the upstream with the -u flag. Try

```
git push -u new-origin --all
```

Comment: i tried this but not working, my git config file looks like below, it might help you to understand                                                                                                                    [remote "origin"]>>
        url = git@github:kiran/kernel-test.git>>
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*>>
[branch "master"]>>
        remote = origin>>
        merge = refs/heads/master>>
[remote "new-origin"]>>
        url = git@github:kiran/q1.git>>
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/new-origin/*